# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, php, custom-options

Error is coming on product detail page in Magento 1.9.2.
Error is for custom options only.

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Complete error is :
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in public_html/dev123/includes/src/Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select.php on line 62`

I think error is coming due to my product detail page not by magento default core files.

My php version is 5.6.3

Answer (score 0):

I checked public_html/dev123/includes/src/Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select.php and yes there was syntax error.

`->addOption`.
I changed it to `$select->addOption('', $this->__('-- Please Select --'));`

It solved now.